# is there any way to run socket.io with only express server

Tags: express, socket.io

My code is as shown below :

```
const express = require('express');

const app = express();

const io = require('socket.io')(app);

io.on('connection',(socket) =>{
    console.log('a user is connected');
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('server started');
});
```

When i run the above code, I get the following error :

`Error: You are trying to attach socket.io to an express request handler function. Please pass a http.Server instance.`

So, is there any way I could run socket.io with only express module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Starting with 3.0, express applications have become request handler functions that you pass to http or http Server instances. You need to pass the Server to socket.io, and not the express application function. Also make sure to call .listen on the server, not the app.

```
var app = require('express')();
var server = require('http').createServer(app);
var io = require('socket.io')(server);  //listen server not app
io.on('connection', function(){ /* … */ });
server.listen(3000);
```